# 'result' or 'their result' in this context

Tags: grammar

Here are my constructions:

1. As part of his academic activities, he conducted research focused on **design**, implementation and operation of novel algorithms using artificial intelligence. Within the framework of his research he developed four solutions and presented **result** in his four scientific publications.
2. As part of his academic activities, he conducted research focused on **design**, implementation and operation of novel algorithms using artificial intelligence. Within the framework of his research he developed four solutions and presented **their result** in his four scientific publications.

I am not sure, which sentence is correct and better?
Should I use 'the' before 'design'?

Comment: You need _something_ before _result_, that is for sure. I'd also pluralize it, since the four solutions are unlikely to have yielded only one result. But whether you write _the results_ or _their results_ doesn't matter much for the meaning, I think. I'd go for the easiest option, _the results_.

Comment: @oerkelens You should really put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change it to:

> As part of his academic activities, he conducted research focused on
>   **the** design, implementation and operation of novel algorithms using
>   artificial intelligence. Within the framework of his research he
>   developed four solutions and presented **the** result**s** in his four
>   scientific publications